# No route matches although there is one in rake routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I get strange `ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches`. The route can be generated:

```
> r = Rails.application.routes
> r.generate controller: :items, action: :index, user_id:1
  => ["/users/1/items", {}]
```

And it is in the `rake routes`:

```
$ rake routes
     user_items GET    /users/:user_id/items(.:format)          items#index
                POST   /users/:user_id/items(.:format)          items#create
  new_user_item GET    /users/:user_id/items/new(.:format)      items#new
 edit_user_item GET    /users/:user_id/items/:id/edit(.:format) items#edit
      user_item GET    /users/:user_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#show
                PUT    /users/:user_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#update
                DELETE /users/:user_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#destroy
(...)
```

But I it's not recognized:

```
r.recognize_path "/users/1/items"
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches "/users/1/items"
```

My `routes.rb`:

```
Sumo2::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users do
    resources :items
  end
  (...)
end
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Do you have `ItemsController` class defined? Without it your route won't be recognized. Perhaps you misspelled it.

```
irb(main):001:0> r = Rails.application.routes
=> #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x1cbba00>
irb(main):002:0> r.recognize_path "/users/1/items"
ActionController::RoutingError: No route matches "/users/1/items"
        ... errors ...
irb(main):003:0> class ItemsController; end # <----------<
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> r.recognize_path "/users/1/items"
=> {:action=>"index", :controller=>"items", :user_id=>"1"}
```