# Cannot create new object in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to create a basic Item creation in rails but I am having trouble creating new item. I want to create item's `name`, say `Wash the dishes`. These are the codes that I have:

Routes:

```
resources :items
```

ItemsController:

```
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
...
  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  def create
    @item = Item.new(item_params)

    if @item.save
      flash[:notice] = "Item was saved!"
      redirect_to @item
    else
      flash.now[:alert] = "ERROR. ERROR."
      render :new
    end
  end
...
  private

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name, :list_id)
  end

end
```

items/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for :item do |f| %>

    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Lastly, schema:

```
  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.integer  "list_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false
  ...
```

I got several different error codes, but this is the one I am currently stuck at (other times it showed different error code or it would simply prints out "ERROR. ERROR." (alert that I setup when `save` fails)

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/items/new"
```

When I go to rake routes:

```
         POST  /items(.:format)                           items#create
new_item GET   /items/new(.:format)                      items#new
```

I followed suggestion from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10994344/no-route-matches-although-there-is-one-in-rake-routes) to check my routes and this is what I have:

```
2.2.2 :019 > r = Rails.application.routes
 => #<ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet:0x007fff323c3230> 
2.2.2 :020 > r.recognize_path "/items/new"
 => {:controller=>"items", :action=>"new"}
```

I have also gone to `rails c` and I was able to create new item manually. (`i = Item.new(name:"Test 123"); i.save`)

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your form. To understand what's wrong, do the following:

1. Start the rails server using `rails s`
2. Go to http://localhost:3000/items/new
3. Instead of filling in the form fields, [view](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000746.htm) the source page
4. Check the form tag. Its submitting the form data to `/items/new`. ie.the action attribute is set to `/items/new`. Why is that?

From the documentation:

> When the model is represented by a string or symbol, if the :url option is not specified, by default the form will be sent back to the current url (We will describe below an alternative resource-oriented usage of form_for in which the URL does not need to be specified explicitly).

```
<form action="/items/new" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
```

In your `routes.rb`, there's no route matching `POST /items/new`

So, modify your form to

```
<%= form_for :item, url: items_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

This generates a form tag which `post`s the data to `/items`rather than `/items/new`.

Or replace your form with

```
<%= form_for @item do |f| %>
 <%= f.text_field :name %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Now, the form will be submitted to `/items`. The advantage of using the second version is you can dry out your form for creating a new object and updating an existing object into a single view(partial).

For more, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object

Comment: That makes sense! So what I had initially `<%= form_for :item do |f| %>`, do you mind explaining what does `:item` represent/ do?

Comment: @Iggy It represents a record object and you can either pass a string or symbol to it. And if you have a form field like `<%= f.text_field :name %>`, it generates the following html, `<input type="text` name="item[name]">, So you can access the name textfield using params[:item][:name]. Hope this helps. I would prefer the second version(I've updated my answer) cause you can use the same partial for both `new` and `edit` actions. For more, see http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for

Answer (score 0):

Try this in items/new.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @item do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```